# Convert to mysql_connect to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello I have this code working but i need to convert the code to work as PDO.
Ive tried so many variations but non worked.
I have $conn as connection.
Thanks in advance.

```
        $projectrfpid = $_GET['projectrfpid'];
        $allRecords = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM projectscostbreakdown WHERE projectscostbreakdown_projectid='.$projectrfpid.' AND projectscostbreakdown_deleted=1 ORDER BY projectscostbreakdown_areaname, projectscostbreakdown_order ASC');
        if(is_resource($allRecords))
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($allRecords))
            {
                ?>
                <tr id="<?php echo $row['projectscostbreakdown_id']; ?>" >
                    <td ><img src="../test/images/icon-drag.png"  height="30" style="cursor:pointer;"/></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo $row['projectscostbreakdown_areaname']; ?>:</b> <?php echo $row['projectscostbreakdown_itemname']; ?><br /><?php echo nl2br($row['projectscostbreakdown_itemdescription']); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: You should show us what you have tried and where you got stuck. Stackoverflow is not a site to ask others to do your work for you.

Comment: Sorry coz ive tried it so many times and have deleted the code once it didnt work. so I was not able to document what i have tried. Will update it soon. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Do this changes..

```
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
$sql ="SELECT * FROM projectscostbreakdown WHERE projectscostbreakdown_projectid='.$projectrfpid.' AND projectscostbreakdown_deleted=1 ORDER BY projectscostbreakdown_areaname, projectscostbreakdown_order ASC";

$allRecords = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($allRecords , MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  {
    ?>
      <tr id="<?php echo $row['projectscostbreakdown_id']; ?>" >
        <td ><img src="../test/images/icon-drag.png"  height="30" style="cursor:pointer;"/></td>
        <td><b><?php echo $row['projectscostbreakdown_areaname']; ?>:</b> <?php echo $row['projectscostbreakdown_itemname']; ?><br /><?php echo nl2br($row['projectscostbreakdown_itemdescription']); ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
I am writing a general format.
Fill up the below fields:
$dbhost     = "";
$dbname     = "";
$dbuser     = "";
$dbpass     = "";

//make the connection

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

$sql="SELECT * FROM projectscostbreakdown WHERE projectscostbreakdown_projectid=:id AND projectscostbreakdown_deleted=1 ORDER BY projectscostbreakdown_areaname, projectscostbreakdown_order ASC";

//always use parameterized queries

$query=$conn->prepare("$sql");

//Bind parameter values using PDO's bindValue method
$query->bindValue(':id', $projectrfpid);  

$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Look up the PDO section in the php manual to learn more.
```